# Alfresco Ldap Use organization in spaces.user_homes.regex.key

Tags: java, spring, ldap, alfresco, alfresco-ldap

Using import from ldap to Alfresco, I´m trying to move the user home folder to use the organization(o) of the user, so I´m using regular expression in my alfresco-global.properties

```
   spaces.user_homes.regex.key=organization
```

In my common-ldap-context.xml

```
  <entry key="cm:organization">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "o" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "???" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
```

And I see that now in the user profile of Alfresco I can see the organization filled.

But when I start up the server Alfresco run the exception

```
    org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonException: 06190000 Can not create a home folder when the {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}organization property is null or empty
```

I´m missing something?, it is not possible use whatever property of Alfresco Person?. I check the content-model.xml and the organization property is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer on below link.It may help you.

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/company-id-field-not-available-user-object

Comment: But what your post describe is just what i'm trying to do, whithout success, I'm missing something here?

Comment: Its not about what you are trying to do ,it is about two fields company id and organization Id.